# Change a textfield Thumb in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to update my textfield to use Red instead of the the green/blueish color. This is my current state.

[image]

This is my code:

```
                TextField(
                    focusNode: focusNode,
                    autocorrect: false,
                    autofocus: false,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    cursorColor: Colors.white,
                    decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        hintText: "FirstName"),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ThemeData/textSelectionHandleColor.html

```
         final theme = Theme.of(context);
         return Theme(data: theme.copyWith(
           textSelectionHandleColor: Colors.red,
           child: TextField(
                focusNode: focusNode,
                autocorrect: false,
                autofocus: false,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                cursorColor: Colors.white,
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    hintText: "FirstName"),
              )
         )
```

Comment: this seems to not work in Flutter 1.17.3. From my investigation is because of this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36220

Comment: There are several theme changes going on, but it worked for me with Flutter 1.19.0-1.0.pre.